# What is spam mail: a point on writing a spam mail filter

Tags: email

I found some methods on filtering spam, one of these is Bayesian technique.

It tells about evaluating content, evaluating word in "content", not the mime info.

I want to ask,

are the mails spam, which is written by human and posted by programs automatically?

Here is a misundertanding. What is spam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the email is composed by humans, if it is unsolicited and sent in bulk it is spam.

Comment: so, bayesian content considering method is off when mail is composed by human, right?

Comment: not really. you could have an email composed by a human which under certain bayesian filters could be seen as spam.

Comment: you mean, i can use detect human composed spams too with bayesian. then i am going to reseacrh for bayesian. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spam is unsolicited bulk e-mail.
If it is something you did not ask for end sent in bulk it is spam.
Your aunt writing to you (even if it's unsolicited) is not spam since it is one-on-one communication.
Receiving a newsletter you signed up for (even if sent in bulk) is not spam since you requested it.